# Object Destruction with Apple Metal API

Tags: c++, lifetime, metal

I was trying out the metal-cpp by exploring the examples provided by apple.

I can see the output of print statement from the constructor but I do not see output from destructor's print statement.

**Why may this be?**

Here's the stripped down version of the code just to show the point:

```
#include <iostream>
#define NS_PRIVATE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define MTL_PRIVATE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define MTK_PRIVATE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define CA_PRIVATE_IMPLEMENTATION

#include <Metal/Metal.hpp>
#include <MetalKit/MetalKit.hpp>

class Renderer
{
    public:
        explicit Renderer( MTL::Device* pDevice );
        ~Renderer();

        void draw( MTK::View* pView );

    private:
        MTL::Device* _pDevice = nullptr;
        MTL::CommandQueue* _pCmdQueue = nullptr;
};

class AppView final : public MTK::ViewDelegate
{
    public:
        explicit AppView( MTL::Device* pDevice );
        ~AppView() override;
        
        void drawInMTKView( MTK::View* pView ) override;

    private:
        Renderer* _pRenderer = nullptr;
};

class AppDelegate final : public NS::ApplicationDelegate
{
    public:
        ~AppDelegate() override;

        static NS::Menu* create_menu_bar();

        void applicationWillFinishLaunching( NS::Notification* pNotification ) override;
        void applicationDidFinishLaunching( NS::Notification* pNotification ) override;
        bool applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed( NS::Application* pSender ) override;

    private:
        NS::Window* _pWindow = nullptr;
        MTK::View* _pView = nullptr;
        MTL::Device* _pDevice = nullptr;
        AppView* _pAppView = nullptr;
};

int main()
{
    auto* pool = NS::AutoreleasePool::alloc()->init();

    AppDelegate appDelegate;

    NS::Application* pSharedApp = NS::Application::sharedApplication();
    pSharedApp->setDelegate( &appDelegate );
    pSharedApp->run();

    pool->release();
    return 0;
}


// -----------------------------------------------  AppView  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AppView::AppView( MTL::Device* pDevice )
    : MTK::ViewDelegate()
    , _pRenderer( new Renderer( pDevice ) )
{ std::cout << "AppView Instantiated. \n"; }

AppView::~AppView()
{ delete _pRenderer; std::cout << "AppView Destroyed. \n";}

void AppView::drawInMTKView( MTK::View* pView )
{ _pRenderer->draw( pView ); }


// -----------------------------------------------  Renderer  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Renderer::Renderer( MTL::Device* pDevice )
    : _pDevice( pDevice->retain() )
{ _pCmdQueue = _pDevice->newCommandQueue(); std::cout << "Renderer Instantiated. \n";}

Renderer::~Renderer()
{
    std::cout << "Renderer Destroyed. \n";
    _pCmdQueue->release();
    _pDevice->release();
}


// -----------------------------------------------  AppDelegate  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
AppDelegate::~AppDelegate()
{
    _pWindow->release();
    _pView->release();
    _pDevice->release();
    delete _pAppView;
}

void AppDelegate::applicationWillFinishLaunching( NS::Notification* pNotification )
{
    NS::Menu* pMenu = create_menu_bar();
    NS::Application* pApp = reinterpret_cast< NS::Application* >( pNotification->object() );
    pApp->setMainMenu( pMenu );
    pApp->setActivationPolicy( NS::ActivationPolicy::ActivationPolicyRegular );
}

void AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching( NS::Notification* pNotification )
{
    CGRect frame = (CGRect) {
        {260.f, 180.f},
        {1200.f, 750.f}
    };

    _pWindow = NS::Window::alloc()->init(
        frame,
        NS::WindowStyleMaskClosable | NS::WindowStyleMaskTitled,
        NS::BackingStoreBuffered,
        false );

    _pDevice = MTL::CreateSystemDefaultDevice();

    _pView = MTK::View::alloc()->init( frame, _pDevice );
    _pView->setColorPixelFormat( MTL::PixelFormat::PixelFormatBGRA8Unorm_sRGB );
    _pView->setClearColor( MTL::ClearColor::Make( 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 1.0 ) );

    _pAppView = new AppView( _pDevice );
    _pView->setDelegate( _pAppView );

    _pWindow->setContentView( _pView );
    _pWindow->setTitle( NS::String::string( "00 - Window", NS::StringEncoding::UTF8StringEncoding ) );

    _pWindow->makeKeyAndOrderFront( nullptr );

    auto* pApp = reinterpret_cast< NS::Application* >( pNotification->object() );
    pApp->activateIgnoringOtherApps( true );
}

bool AppDelegate::applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed( NS::Application* pSender )
{
    return true;
}
```

I expected the destructor to be called and executed which doesn't seem to happen.

Edit:
Any statements after the call to `pSharedApp->run()` does not get executed. I even tried adding some random print statements after call to `run` in `main` and added breakpoint to those statements. Even the debugger doesn't stop at those breakpoint after I close application window.
The program exist code is 0 though.

Comment: Which destructor are you talking about?  Your `AppDelegate` is destroyed as part of application shutdown, and it's quite possible that the destructor runs after std::cout has closed.

Comment: @TimRoberts `std::cout` should still be available at the end of `main` when `AppDelegate` is destroyed

Comment: @TimRoberts I was talking about the `~Renderer()` and `~AppView()`.

Comment: I just added another `std::cout` statement in `~AppDelegate()` and that too doesn't seem to be executed.

Comment: Side note: underscored identfier names are reserved for compiler designers and platform specific libraries. Consider changing your naming conventions. Maybe `m_` prefix for data members...

Comment: Console IO might have been disabled in project configuration. Use a log file instead: `static std::ofstream my_log("my_log_file.txt");`. Now use `my_log` instead of `std::cout`. Check the file in a text editor, after the program terminates.

Comment: @Red.Wave [only underscores followed by a capital letter are resvered](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers), `_pWindow` is fine whereas `_PWindow` would be reserved

Comment: @Red.Wave I tried logging to file as you said and still no change.

Comment: @rosxnb comment out the call to `run` method and both calls to `setDelegate` and test again.

Comment: @Red.Wave commenting the call to `run` does execute the `std::cout` statement from destructor of `AppDelegate` but commenting out `setDelegate` call doesn't make change on executing print statement.

Comment: But when I comment out `run` at `main` function, the app doesn't "run" so I am basically just making an object of `AppDelegate` and destroying it without doing anything with it!

Comment: You are triggering some sort of UB. You need read the docs for Metal. When you execute `run`, the program does something unexpected: either a termination due to an exception occurs or some serious bug overwrites the data. You need to identify whether the problem is on your side(likely), or on the library side(unlikely).

Comment: The program exits with the status code of `0`. It seems that **any statements/expressions** after the call to `run` doesn't get executed. I tried placing a breakpoint and even the debugger doesn't stop at the breakpoint. I am using lldb to debug.

While debugging I do get some messages like:
```
[Window] Warning: Window NSWindow 0x61400000b640 ordered front from a non-active application and may order beneath the active application's windows.
[client] No error handler for XPC error: Connection invalid
```
But upon searching about these messages, they doesn't sound "harmful".